# Why is my edit mesh disappearing when zoomed in?

Tags: mesh, edit-mode

I can't think why or how this is happening (new to blender) but the mesh disappears when zoomed in

Image ref 1: here you can see the mesh appears to be hiding behind surface, which is it isn't

[image]

Image ref 2: but when I zoom out it shows the edit mesh

[image]

I don't believe I've changed anything or pressed any buttons because I've just opened the file.

Comment: Believe it or not, here, the error is actually when you are zoomed out.  It is called "z-fighting" and occurs because there isn't enough precision in the view's depth map to know which mesh goes in front of which mesh.  To resolve this, increase your near clip, or decrease your far clip, or both.  This can be done in sidebar/view.  The reason you can't see your vertices when close is because you have modifiers with "display in edit mode" enabled; look at the buttons to the right of each modifier's name.

Comment: Ah, it was checking or rather unchecking the display in edit mode - thanks